# ATOMIC_MOVE gives exceptions

Tags: java, file, nio

I am in the middle of automating a series of actions that we do a lot in order to gain some time. This involves moving files around and starting some batches.

In this particular situation, I am trying to copy a file from one location to another location. All works fine, until I try to use the `ATOMIC_MOVE` copy option. This is my code:

```
private void copyToDropFolder(Datafile datafile, String company) throws IOException{
    Path datafilePath = datafile.getDataPath();  
    String dropFolder = locations.getLocationFor("default");
    Path dropPath = Paths.get(dropFolder, company.toUpperCase(),locations.getLocationFor("drop"), datafile.getFileName());
    Files.copy(datafilePath, dropPath, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
}
```

I have checked and resolved the locations of datafilePath and dropPath, they are both valid.  I have tried with the other 2 standard copy options, and the program runs fine. It is only for `ATOMIC_MOVE` that I get an `UnsupportedOperationException`. It is not that I absolutely need that specific option, but I am curious why I wouldn't work. I cant really find any other reports on this issue. I am doing this on a Windows 7 machine.

Am I missing something? Or is the `ATOMIC_MOVE` just not supported?

Comment: Why do you try and `ATOMIC_MOVE` a _copy_ operation? This does not make sense. Or do you want to use `link()`?

Comment: What file system type are you trying this on? It may be that the operation is not supported (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html)

Comment: @fge You are right... when you look at it in that way, it doesnt make sense. But having an ATOMIC_MOVE option in an enum called StandardCopyOption doesn't make much sense either :/ .You point that out nicely, i didnt think about it in that way. As for now, i dont really want to use it, i just tried it out and it fails. I am puzzled as why it would fail.

Comment: @DaDaDom I am doing this on a windows 7 machine, so i would say NTFS.

Comment: It fails because you cannot copy atomically -- but you can _link_ atomically, as long as the source and target paths are on the same filesystem. Look at [`Files.createLink()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createLink(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path)), this is probably what you meant.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As API [says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29), `ATOMIC_MOVE` is not supported for `copy()`, but for `move()` only.

Comment: Thanks! i missed that one. I focussed entirely on [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html)

Answer (score 5):

`ATOMIC_MOVE` is for moving operations, not copying operations.

On the other hand, you can create so-called "hard links" using [`Files.createLink()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createLink%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29). There is also `createSymbolicLink()` but this is probably not what you want here.

And of course, `.createLink()` will only work if the source and destination paths are on the same filesystem.